# Yahoo Pipes String change first word to the last word

Tags: string, loops, yahoo-pipes

I don't know yahoo pipes so much, i am just wandering, is it possible to make the `first word` moved to be the `last word` of sentence ?

for example, i got some feed, with an item title like this

`Stackoverflow : The best way to do self-programming learning`

then i want to move the first word, which is `Stackoverflow` to be the last word like this

`The best way to do self-programming learning - Stackoverflow`

how do i do that ?

in my logic :
we need to separate the first words from the feeds, then store them into *"memory" or some kind like that"*

then we use `string builder` then take the stored words to the last sentence. but i don't know 'the tools' that works like *"memory" or some kind like that*

**updates :**

how do i join both `string regex` loops into 1 items ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipes themselves will serve as memory. :-)

a) create a regex operator stripping the colon and everything in front.

b) create a regex operator stripping the colon and everything after.

c) pass the string to *both* a) and b).

d) create a string builder for [input-from-a] + " - " + [input-from-b].

Tried sharing an example here: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=68b135e6b9a182a8bf9e1f329eaaf6f5

[image]

Comment: i input this text `Stackoverflow : blabla blabla blabla` it returns null ?

can you show me where to find regex yahoo pipes reference ?

Comment: @Cignitor If you recreate my example, clicking on the "String Builder" operation should show "two three - one" in the debug output at the bottom.  Anyway, I haven't looked at the documentation - try the [?] in the upper right of the "String Regex" operation window. :-)

Comment: i see, i have another problem, you used single text, while i get the text from feed, so it should be collection feed, we need to wrap the tools inside loops. and i can't combine both of loop containing string regex into 1 collection string builder. how do i do that ?

Comment: Looping is done automatically - items are passed through the piping one by one. You could just deconstruct the item, operate on the string, and reconstruct the item.  --- But, it's probably easier to just regex directly on the item.  For example a replace operation from `^([^:]*):(.*)$` to `$2 - $1` over the `title` attribute will work.

Comment: can you help me to develop your idea through image ? i got stuck on joining both loops, we need `loop` filled with `string builder`. but the `loop` itself only receive from 1 pipe.

when i use union, the string become awkward that i don't expected to

Comment: Drop the split, and just do it all with one attribute-specific regexp.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19281/discussion-between-cignitor-and-deestan)

Comment: could you help me by make another example using `fetch feed` sources please ?